# How to add additional content to thymeleaf head tag if it comes from a fragment?

Tags: templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In django I can do:

```
 <head>
{% block content %}

     (....) ---------> content from a partial template goes here.

{% endblock %}

     (....) ---------> I can add aditional stuff here if I need to.

<head>
```

wherever I like. (example: use the same head in all templates but one page requires an aditional css file or script)

I understand that In thymeleaf I need to define an entire tag as a fragment to which I can no longer add anything else and need to use as is.

My question is how would I go about to achieve the above example in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a folder under resources/templates called fragments. After create a file fragment.html then in your head:

```
 <head>

     <div th:replace="fragments/fragment :: fragment"></div>


     (....) ---------> you can add aditional stuff here if you need to.

<head>
```

And in your fragment.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
<body>
  <div th:fragment="fragment" th:remove="tag">
    (....) ---------> content from a partial template goes here.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**th:replace** will actually substitute the host tag by the fragment’s

**th:remove="tag"** removed the container div of the fragment included

As a result you should get:

```
 <head>

     (....) ---------> content from a partial template goes here.

     (....) ---------> you can add aditional stuff here if you need

<head>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just add this into the head tag:

```
<head>
  <th:block th:replace="fragments/headContent :: baseContent"></th:block>
  <!-- other blocks -->
</head>
```

In Fragment file:

```
<head>
  <th:block th:fragment="baseContent">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <style> **your style tag content** </style>
  </th:block>
</head>
```